# Convergence of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

> Find out if the following integral diverges or converges:
>   $$
> \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx 
> $$

---

First I split the integral as $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx $.

- For $\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx $ , I prove $\ln(1+x^2)< x^2$, using that I can prove $\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx $ converges, but it take too long so is there shorter way to do this problem?
- For $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx $ , I have no idea how to do this problem.

Comment: Why does it take too long? How did you go about the proof? For the second integral, note that for large $x$ the denominator is roughly $x^3$.

Comment: You can use that $\ln$ is asymptotically smaller than any $n$th root

Comment: I would be inclined to say that, for large x, $ln(1+ x^2)$ can be approximated by $ln(x^2)= 2ln(x)$.  And $\sqrt{2x^5+ x^6}$ by $\sqtrt{x^6}= x^3$.  So the integrand is of the order of $\frac{ln(x)}{x^3}$.  That goes to 0 much faster than $\]frac{1}{x}$ so is integrable..

Comment: @user247327 Proper notation is $2\ln(x)$ or $2\ln x,$ not $2ln(x).$ Writing \ln not only prevents italicization, but results in proper spacing to the left and right of $\ln.$ Notice that there is more space to the right of $\ln$ in $\ln x$ than in $\ln(x).$ If you just write $ln,$ you don't get context-dependent spacing.

Comment: can i use $ln(1+x^2)<x^2$ without proving it? is it a known fact or something.

Comment: @pmac : For all $x\in\mathbb R,$ we have $\ln(1+x) \le x$ and if $x\ne0$ then $\ln(1+x)<x.$ Just observe that $y=x$ is the tangent line at $x=0$ to the curve $y=\ln(1+x)$ and that $y=\ln(1+x)$ is concave downward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a short way: use *equivalents* to remove unnecessary details:

- For $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,\mathrm d x$, the integrand is equivalent near $0$ to
  $$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x^5}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2x}},$$
  and the integral of the latter converges on $(0,1]$.
- For $\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,\mathrm dx $, the integrand is equivalent, when $x\to\infty$, to
  $$\frac{\ln (x^2)}{\sqrt {x^6}}=\frac{2\ln x}{x^3}= \frac{\ln x}{x}\frac1{x^2}=o\Bigl(\frac1{x^2}\Bigr),$$
  and the integral of $1/x^2$ converges on $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Typo: the square root should include $x$.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: i don't really understand the equivalent thing can you explain it for me or can you give me the link to any site that explain it

Comment: If g(x) is equivalent to f(x) at x=k, that means lim (x->k) of g(x)-f(x) = 0

Comment: @Gabe: Not really: it means  that $\lim_{x\to k}\dfrac{g(x)]{f(x)}=1$ and it is compatible with multiplication and division, *not* with addition or subtraction.

Comment: @pmac: It is a notion of *asymptotic analysis*, along with the *big Oh* and *little oh* notations. It is a very powerful tool, as you can get  rid of unnecessary details in a function for limit related problems. You can have an idea looking at the Wikipedia page on [Asymptotic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). One result seems to be missing: a function is equivalent to a constant at a point $a$ if and only if its limit at $a$ is equal to this constant.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most powerful tools for deciding convergence of improper integrals (infinite series in the discrete case) is the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test). However, making strict comparisons can be tedious and not necessary. The [limit version of the comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) is usually much easier to apply.

Suppose one wants to decide whether $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx<\infty$, where $f$ is some nonnegative continuous function here. But $f$ is of some "ugly" expression that is hard to integrate or even hard to compare directly with certain known function on the whole interval $(0,1)$. However, if one has the following two easy to get facts for some positive function $g$:

- $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=C$ with $0\le C<\infty$;
- $\int_0^1g(x)\,dx<\infty$.

Then we can tell that $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx<\infty$. We have similar arguments for analyzing $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$. 
See for instance [this set of lecture notes](https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf). Such arguments would *justify* the [asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) in [Bernard's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3454645/9464).

---

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\cdot\sqrt{x}
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{x^2}\cdot
\frac{x^2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
and
$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx<\infty,
$
we can conclude by the limiting comparison test that 
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx<\infty.
$$

On the other hand, since
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\cdot x^2
=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{x}\cdot\frac{x^3}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}
= 0 
$$
 and $
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx<\infty,
$
 we have
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx<\infty.
$$

---

† In the argument above, one can use [L'Hopital rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to find the following two limits. 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1,\quad
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach on $[0,1]$ seems fine. For the other part, you can verify that:

$$\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}} \le \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {x^6}}=\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{x^3} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln (1 + x^2)}{x^3}\,\mbox{d}x = \ln 2$$

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun of it.*

The convergence issues having been clearly explained and one answer for the value showing that a CAS is able to find a (nasty) antiderivative, the result is in fact
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log (1 + x^2)}{\sqrt {2x^5 + x^6}}\,dx=\frac{1}{3} \log \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-1+i+\sqrt{-1-2 i}\right)^{-\sqrt{4-2 i}}\,\,
   \left(-1-i+\sqrt{-1+2 i}\right)^{-\sqrt{4+2 i}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

For small $x$, $$\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{x^2\sqrt{2x+x^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2x}}+o(x^{-1/2}).$$

For large $x$, $$\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{x^2\sqrt{2x+x^2}}=\frac{\log(x)}{x^3}+o\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x^3}\right)=o\left(x^{-2}\right).$$

In both cases, the integrals of the asymptotic expressions do converge.